# Is it possible to implement Row Level Security by User in Azure SQL DB and Access the User Specific Rowset on ASP.Net 3.1 Web App

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-webapps

I have an Azure SQL DB and a set of users who need remote/mobile access to data in this database. I would like to implement Row Level Security to return a filtered subset to each user.

Row Level Security I can handle, but am stuck trying to figure out whether a ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web App can forward the user authentication to Azure SQL DB or only authenticate the web app on the Azure SQL DB.

The only information that I have found is to use a Managed Identity to connect which grants the App access to the DB and effectively bypasses the user's credentials.

Is this actually possible to achieve? How do I sign in the user to the DB through the Web App using AzureAD authentication?

Via my DbContext, this works for App Authentication

```
var conn = (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();
conn.AccessToken = 
          (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider())
          .GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/")
          .Result;
```

But if I try to use AzureAD authentication, I get an error: `SqlException: Login failed for user`

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddAzureAD(options => config.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Comment: thank you @Nafis Islam for tidying my code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mu understanding, you want to use Azure AD users to login in Azure SQL. If so, please refer to the following steps

1. [Add Azure AD user as database user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities)
2. Create Azure AD application
3. Configure permissions
   [image]
4. Configure Azure AD auth

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                  .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.Configure<AzureADOptions>(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {

                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.Scope.Add("https://database.windows.net//.default"); // get token fro azure sql
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                {
                    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
                    string currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(
                       request.Scheme,
                       request.Host,
                       request.PathBase,
                       options.CallbackPath);

                    var code = context.ProtocolMessage.Code;
                    string signedInUserID = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                    IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                              .Create(options.ClientId)
                              .WithClientSecret(options.ClientSecret)
                              .WithRedirectUri(currentUri)
                              .WithAuthority(options.Authority)
                              .Build();

                    AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(options.Scope, code)
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                    context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);

                };

            });
```

5. require access token

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                              .Create(ClientId)
                              .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                              .WithRedirectUri(currentUri)
                              .WithAuthority(Authority)
                              .Build();
 var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();
                AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilent(scope, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .ExecuteAsync();
var conn = (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)new SqlConnection(ContionStr);
conn.AccessToken = result.AccessToken
```

For more details about how to implement Azure AD auth, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview)

Comment: Thank you, this is hugely helpful. I'm currently getting an error stating No authenticationScheme specified and no DefaultChallengeScheme, but I thought those were assigned `.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and  `.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme`. I wonder if I've referenced the wrong extensions.
For `AuthenticationResult` I needed to add `Microsoft.Identity.Client` and for `ClaimTypes` I needed `System.Security.Claims`. Finally for `UriHelper` I was missing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions`.

Comment: @sbitaxi Please install sdk `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` Then use `services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and ` services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme`. It is ok for me.

Comment: I did have that sdk and am still trying to determine what's causing the error. It  appears to be something to do with changes OpenIdConnect in 3.1 vs 2.1. Am trying to verify. I grabbed a sample and used your code in #4 which worked, but the dotnet version is 2.1 vs 3.1 which is what I was using.
Microsoft is also in the process of migrating their documentation to Microsoft.Identity.Web which makes things a little confusing since some of the code targets 3.1 and some 2.1.